# Как выводить записи из нескольких групп Вконтакте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vkontakte-api

Есть код, который выводит посты из группы вконтакте в блок "answerPlaceHolder", так вот если я хочу также выводить посты и с другой группы вконтакте, только уже в другой блок "betaFeed" как это реализовать что бы они друг другу не мешали?

```
    <div id="answerPlaceHolder"></div>
    <div id="betaFeed"></div>
        <script>
var placeHolder = $('#answerPlaceHolder');
var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-78812318&count=4&filter=all&v=5.45';
  var answer;
  $.ajax
  ({
        url: url,                
        type: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response)
        {
          answer = response;

          answer.response.items.forEach(function(item)
          {
            var item2Append = $('<div class= "blog-post"></div>');          

            if((item.text != 'undefined') && (item.text != ''))
            {             
             // item2Append.append('<div class="blog-header">' + item.text + '</div>');
              console.log(item.text);
            }

            if(                
                (typeof(item.attachments) !== 'undefined') &&
                (item.attachments[0].type == 'photo') && 
                (typeof(item.attachments[0].photo.photo_604) !== 'undefined')
              )
            {              
              item2Append.append('<div class="blog-header">' + item.text + '</div> <img class="blog-img" src="' + item.attachments[0].photo.photo_604 + '"><br><div class="blog-text">' + item.attachments[0].photo.text + '</div><div class="blog-share"><a href="http://gamer-by-life.com/share/?title='+ item.text +  '&img='+ item.attachments[0].photo.photo_604 + '&time='+item.date + '&text=' + item.attachments[0].photo.text + '"><img src="share.png"></a></div>');
              //console.log(item.attachments[0].photo.photo_604); 
            }

            console.log('******************************\n');
            if(item2Append.children().length != 0)
            {
              item2Append = item2Append.add('<br>');
              placeHolder.append(item2Append);   
            }

          });                 
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
          console.log('Ошибка');
            console.log(error);
        }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смею предположить, например, таким образом:

```js
$(function() {

  var placeHolder = $('#answerPlaceHolder');
  getVKposts(-41633702);
  getVKposts(-22822305);

  function getVKposts(groupID) {
    var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=' + groupID + '&count=3&filter=all&v=5.45';
    var answer;
    var d = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'get',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response) {
        var answer;
        answer = response;
        answer.response.items.forEach(function(item) {
          var item2Append = $('<div class= "blog-post"></div>');
          if (
            (typeof(item.attachments) !== 'undefined') &&
            (item.attachments[0].type == 'photo') &&
            (typeof(item.attachments[0].photo.photo_604) !== 'undefined')
          ) {
            item2Append.append('<div class="blog-header">' + item.text + '</div> <img class="blog-img" src="' + item.attachments[0].photo.photo_604 + '"><br><div class="blog-text">' + item.attachments[0].photo.text + '</div><div class="blog-share"><a href="http://gamer-by-life.com/share/?title=' + item.text + '&img=' + item.attachments[0].photo.photo_604 + '&time=' + item.date + '&text=' + item.attachments[0].photo.text + '"><img src="share.png"></a></div>');
          }
          placeHolder.append(item2Append);
        });
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log('Ошибка');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="answerPlaceHolder"></div>
<div id="betaFeed"></div>
```

Comment: А есть ли способ что бы для какой то определенной группы count постов был допустим не 3, а 10 ?

Comment: @arthru просто вызывай getVKjson(-41633702, 10), допиши function getVKjson(groupID, num) и внутри функции вставь num

Comment: Можете дать пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто не пойму куда это вставить что-бы норм работало, и еще можно ли как то исправить именно порядок записей, а то когда обновляем страницу постоянно в разброс то 1 группа в начале то  вторая.